# evaluate Gram–Schmidt process

Tags: linear-algebra

i have question related to Gram–Schmidt process,  in this process there is  used such procedure
$proj_u(v)=\frac{(v,u)\cdot u}{(u,u)}$  where  $(v,u)$  is  defined as inner product,so my my question is if  $v=(1,2,3)$ and $u=(0,2,1)$  then does this projection equal to
  $ \frac{(1,2,3)\cdot(0,2,1)}{ ((0,2,1)\cdot(0,2,1))}\cdot u$?  or if we continue  this procedure,first multiplication gives us  $1\cdot 0+2\cdot 2+3\cdot1=7$, second    would be  $0\cdot0+2\cdot2+1\cdot1=5$  so $\frac 75\cdot u$?  or is there another  step or other procedure for this calculation?please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only trying to find $\operatorname{proj}_u(v)$ then that's accurate.